# How can I compare the performance of model selected by AIC and K-fold cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, information-criteria

guys. I try to compare the model selection criterions. The model is built as a linear regression with 20 explanatory variables. More precisely, what I did so far, is spilting the data into training(70%) and test(30%). Then I use forward/backward stepwise selection in training data to pick up the best model by criterions, like adjusted R-Squared, Mallow's Cp, AIC and BIC. And the models will be tested of MSE in test data (the model with least test error will be treated as the best model). I also used the 10-fold cross validation to pick up the best model but with **all data**. 
Now I have a question: how can I compare the performance of the model selected by AIC with 17 variables and the model selected by 10-fold cross validation with 15 variables ?

Comment: Both the train-test and CV methods give you unbiased prediction on a held-out test set, so that should be a fair comparison. Although, it's not clear to me why you're doing both - CV is essentially just repeated train-test splits, and you can still use AIC as your optimizing function within CV. AIC and CV are completely orthogonal, as they deal with entirely different parts of the model training process, but you frame the question as an either/or, which is a little confusing.

Comment: @NuclearWang I used CV as a model selection criteria, try to compare the results from other model selection criterions

Comment: Cross-validation is not a model selection criterion. Your model is trained to optimize some quantity, whether that's accuracy, or AIC, or F1, or something else - that is your model selection criterion. Cross-validation is a method of splitting data to measure those quantities in training data and a held-out test set. You can't pick a model to optimize cross-validation, you pick a model to optimize some criterion (like AIC) over the cross-validation splits. Within cross-validation, you can optimize for whatever you want.

Comment: @NuclearWang thank you for your suggestion,  can I use the test error MSE from the cross-validation as a model selection to pick up the best model?

Comment: Test errors should not be used to pick a model - test data is only used for evaluation of models, and should never be used for anything other than that. You should only use it to get an estimate of how well your model will perform on other, as-yet-unseen data. If you use test data to pick a model, you a biasing your result. If you want one model, just run your method on all the data you have one time. The cross-validation will give you an estimate of how good your model building method is, but to build one final model, just use all the data.